# Replace string does not work in python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I have a template file: `'template.txt'` like below:

```
class Core_Model_DbTable_{table_name} extends YouNet_Db_Table
{
    const TYPE_PRINTED      = 1;
    const TYPE_DIGITAL      = 2;

    protected $_name = '{table_name}';
    protected $_rowClass = 'Core_Model_{table_name:short}';
}
```

And I use Python 3.2 to read that file and try to replace:

> - {table_name} => Coupons
> - {table_name:short} => Coupon

and here my code:

```
in_file = open("template.txt","r")
text    = in_file.read()
in_file.close()
txt = text.replace("{table_name}","Coupons")
txt = text.replace("{table_name:short}","Coupon")
```

But the output only shows the result:

c:\Python32\python.exe builder.py

```
<?php

class Core_Model_DbTable_{table_name} extends YouNet_Db_Table
{
        const TYPE_PRINTED      = 1;
        const TYPE_DIGITAL      = 2;

        protected $_name = '{table_name}';
        protected $_rowClass = 'Core_Model_Coupon';
}
```

Could you please tell me anything is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have misspelled the name of your variable: "txt" vs "text".